# For loops in python to find the sum of a list

Tags: python, loops

I have a question concerning lists in python. Currently I have some code which looks like this:

```
muaverage = (w[0] * mu[0] + w[1] * mu[1])
```

where w and mu are both lists containing 2 variables.
While w and mu contain only two variables the code works fine, however I would like to add more values to these lists, for which purpose iterating through the lists to find the sum seems most appropriate. I have attempted the following

```
for i in range(0,len(mu)):
    muaverage = sum(w[i] * mu[i])
```

but this has been displaying an error. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: `sum(i*j for i,j in zip(w,m))`?

Comment: Could you mention what error are you getting?

Comment: the error says object 'float' not iterable!

Comment: The problem with your loop is that you overwrite the previous value in each iteration. Also, you are trying to get the sum of a single integer. Also, that's not an average.

Comment: `numpy.dot()` would also work

Answer (score 5):

There are two problems with your code:

- you are overwriting the previous value of `muaverage` in each iteration
- you are trying to get the `sum` of a single numeric value

Instead, you can *either* use a regular `for` loop:

```
muaverage = 0                  # initialize before the loop
for i in range(0,len(mu)):
    muaverage += w[i] * mu[i]  # add to current value with +=
```

*Or* use `sum` with a generator expression:

```
muaverage = sum(w[i] * mu[i] for i in range(len(mu)))
```

Or `sum` and `zip`, as [suggested by @yatu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54552421/for-loops-in-python-to-find-the-sum-of-a-list/54552557#comment95904661_54552421):

```
muaverage = sum(x * y for x, y in zip(w, mu))
```

Note, however, that `muaverage` is not really an average; for that, you'd still have to divide it by the number of elements, or the sum of weights (?) in `w` for a weighted average.

Comment: Perhaps, what is wanted is actually a weighted average, for which you would divide by the sum of the weights. On a similar note, `numpy.average()` accepts a `weight` parameter precisely for that.

Comment: @norok2 Good point, that makes very much sense, particularly with the second array being called `w`. Why don't you post that as another answer?

Comment: Thanks Tobias and the rest of you for your help, problem solved

Comment: Another idea just for fun `sum(starmap(lambda x,y: x*y, zip(w,mu)))`

Comment: @yatu Surely you mean `sum(itertools.starmap(operator.mul, zip(w, mu)))`?

Comment: Nicer with operator I guess :-)

Comment: Similar to the previous question but how can I do the same thing for:                 
std = [STDV(lbound[0],ubound[0]),STDV(lbound[1],ubound[1])] such that std == a list of these elements

Comment: Thats a different question @j_abrams. I suggest you right a new question for this and you'll surely get some help

Answer (score 1):

You seems to be after a (inner) dot product between `mu` and `w`.
For implementing this yourself, simply refer to @tobias_k answer. However, in the standard package for numerical arrays in Python, i.e. NumPy, the function `dot()` or the operator `@` (in Python >=3.5) would do what you are asking, i.e. the (inner) dot product.

```
import numpy as np

# define some dummy objects
mu = list(range(0, 10))
w = list(range(10, 20))

muaverage = sum(x * y for x, y in zip(mu, w))
# muaverage == 735

muaverage = np.dot(mu, w)
# muaverage == 735

# operands of `@` should be `numpy.array()`
mu = np.array(mu)
w = np.array(w)
muaverage = mu @ w
# muaverage == 735
```

But your naming suggests that perhaps you may be after a weighted average, for which you would use `average()` which does accept a `weight` parameter, e.g.

```
import numpy as np

# define some dummy objects
mu = list(range(0, 10))
w = list(range(10, 20))

muaverage = np.average(mu, weights=w)
# muaverage == 5.068965517241379

muaverage = np.dot(mu, w) / np.sum(w)
# muaverage == 5.068965517241379
```

**(EDITED to better include `np.dot()`).**